# How to change cell color based on today's date in Excel 2010

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

How do I Change cell color in Excel 2010 for upcoming or past dates based on 90 days from today. I would be great if I could use 2 color scale but one color will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional formatting. Use the condition `=NOW() + 90` with the `Less Than...` condition.

Choose whatever color format you want.

If you want to have multiple colors you can have multiple rules with different conditions where you vary the `90` from the above condition.