# In excel 2010 how do I change the cell colour to red if the date entered is 2 weeks or more in the past?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have a spread sheet and I want the colour of the cell to change to red when the date entered is two weeks (or more) ago as this will immediately show me when work is overdue so I can chase it up.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change cell color based on today's date in Excel 2010](http://superuser.com/questions/445783/how-to-change-cell-color-based-on-todays-date-in-excel-2010), also see [How do I use Conditional Formatting based on due dates in Excel 2013?](http://superuser.com/questions/862205/how-do-i-use-conditional-formatting-based-on-due-dates-in-excel-2013)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Quick-start-Apply-conditional-formatting-6B6F7C2A-5D62-45A1-8F67-584A76776D67) to achieve this. You will use a formula to calculate todays date against the value in the cell (Which must be of a date format).

The formula would be along the lines of:

`=(TODAY()-13)>A1`

Depending on how many days you want to compare against, and which cell has your date.

Note, this will trigger blank cells as they are treated as being 'before' todays date. If you wish to apply this to blank cells, use the following:

`=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($A1)),(TODAY()-13)>$A1)`

This will check the cell is not blank first.

The below image should help you if needed.

[image: Excel Formula]

Comment: Thank you. How do I replicate that formula down the table? When I click on the button with the red diagonal arrow at the end of the formula (as shown above) and select the rest of the column, it turns the column red even though there is nothing entered in those cells.

Comment: @N.Knight It will do, as there is no date in those cells, therefore today is after this date.  I have updated this answer with an updated formula to check for a blank cell also. If this has resolved the problem for you, please accept the answer.